# Which work of science fiction was first to link alien invaders with Halley's Comet?

Tags: aliens, history-of, science-fiction-genre, origins, alien-invasion

The 1985 movie [*Lifeforce*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifeforce_%28film%29) featured space vampires traveling in the tail of Halley's Comet. Is *Lifeforce* the first work of science fiction to link invaders from space with Halley's Comet?

Comment: There was apparently a Halley's Comet video game  that involved aliens accompanying the comet. It came out in 1986, so "only" isn't true but "first" might be. Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_Comet_(video_game)

Comment: Also closely concurrent was the book by Benford and Brin:  [Heart of the Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_of_the_Comet), published in 1986.

Comment: The movie Lifeforce was based on a novel by Colin Wilson called The space Vampires (1976) but I cant tell you if Halleys comet is used in the book like it is in the movie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1942 book *The Comet Kings* featuring "The Futuremen"

> Trapped in the depths of Halley's Comet, the Futuremen battle fourth-dimensional monsters in a titanic struggle to save the system's solar energy

[image]

Here's a relevant excerpt:

> "Look, Simon! The first slops that vanished did so near the orbit of Uranus. The next ones disappeared further Sunward. The location of disappearances has
>   steadily moved in a Sunward direction."
>   "That's true," the Brain admitted. "Does it mean anything?"
>   "I don't know," Curt muttered. "But Halley's Comet has also been steadily moving in a Sunward direction, during these vanishings." His eyes flashed.
>   "Simon, I know it sounds insane, but I think that Halley's Comet has something to do with this mystery!"

And:

> "They were all drawn into the comet by a magnetic beam, the same as we," he declared. "Simon, that beam was deliberately projected to seize us!"
>   "Aye, lad," came the answer of the helpless Brain. "There's intelligence and menace inside Halley's comet."

Comment: That's worth a cigar... ;)

Comment: @MajorStackings I didn't even notice that *you*'d ask the question. I was just like "Hmm, that's interesting."